# programmatically add one or more condition filter in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How do i get all lines from raw csv file by filtering with multiple condition.
I have raw file and i change it into DF.

```
val text =  sc.textFile("hdfs:///data/text/")
case class TextFile(id:String, time:String,text:String)


val textDf = text.map(_.split(",")).map(s => TextFile(s(0).toString(),
                                        s(1).toString(),
                                        s(2).toString()
                                        )).toDF()
```

And i also have condition file.

```
val findWord =  sc.textFile("hdfs:///condition/text.txt").collect.toList
```

if i was known what the condition are, i just need to write down like this

```
textDf.filter(lower($"text").contains("ok") || lower($"text").contains("yes"))
```

There was various conditions so i try like this

```
val test = findWord.map(v => s"""lower($$"text").contains("$v")""").mkString(" || ");

textDf.filter(test).collect
```

but i can't run it. Also print(test) is same as condition what i need, can't use in df filter.

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
```

How do i solve my problem?

Thanks for your help and advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to build a String condition is not the best practice I would say. You can **manipulate the Column class** instead. Like this:

```
val condition = words.map(v => col("text").contains(s"$v")).reduce(_||_)
```

Which produces the following Column:

```
condition: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = (((contains(text, yes) OR contains(text, ok)) OR contains(text, k)) OR contains(text, y))
```

**On an example** :

```
 val words = List("yes", "ok", "k", "y")
 val condition = words.map(v => col("text").contains(s"$v")).reduce(_||_)
 val df = Seq( ("word"), ("text"), ("ok"), ("abc"), ("y") ).toDF("text")
 df.filter(condition).show
```

**Output:**

```
+----+
|text|
+----+
|  ok|
|   y|
+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically construct you filtering condition based on the `findWords` file. Supposing `findWords` is a `List[String]` you can do something like this

```
val accFilter = lit("1") === "1" // a column that has a default true condition
val composedFilter = findWords
 .foldLeft(accFilter){case(accFilter, word) => {
   accFilter || lower($"text").contains(word)
}}
```

this will make the filtering be build based on `||` condition. Then you simply do

```
textDf.filter(composedFilter)
```